# Try & Except in a while loop

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, while-loop, try-catch

Still new at programming, I am trying to create a script which detects a port is unavailable on a remote host and change iptables & send out a single notification.

I am running Ubuntu 16.04, I am using Python3, i am using the os module to send the email & change IPtables

I can almost get it working however, trying to get it to email just once is proving a challange.

```
import socket
import sys
import time
import datetime
import os
import logging

#Variables
remote_host = "syslog1"
drop = os.system("iptables-restore < iptables.conf")
undrop = os.system("iptables-restore < DR-iptables.conf")
print ('Starting Syslog DR Plan.')

# run continuously

while True:
    time.sleep(1)
    for remote_port in [514]:
        sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        sock.settimeout(60)
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        now_text = now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
        plco = 0

        try:
            sock.connect((remote_host, remote_port))
            print((now_text, 'Port is Open on', remote_port))


        except:
            socket.timeout
            plco = 1

    if plco == 1:
        undrop
        logging.basicConfig(filename='/var/log/syslog',level=logging.DEBUG , format='%(asctime)s %(message)s', datefmt='%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p')
        logging.error('#### Syslog DR Invoked - Immediate action required ####')
        os.system("mail -s '# INVESTIGATE IMMEDIATELY - SYSLOG1 port 514 unreachable #' alert@test.com < ./panic.txt")
        print( 'Port is closed')

    else:
        pass
sock.close()
```

I suspect I need to do one of two things but thus far have failed. One was to define it as a function then call the function then set another function to email depending on the output.

Can anyone suggest where to go, or a better way to do this (I may be doing things the hard/wrong way).

Many thanks

Comment: Your `except` block catches any and all exceptions - you should change this to `except socket.timeout:`; that way, any unexpected behaviour still throws an exception (like keyboard interupts, for example)

Comment: Also, make sure you post executable code; you have a few spelling errors there.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I shall another look and let you know how i get on.

Comment: Thanks, I now have an if statement which i didn't before. Unfortuantely, it stills sends multiple emails. Not sure what else to do except maybe rethinking my life ;)

Comment: What exaclty do you mean by 'multiple emails' ? Your code should send an email every second, if the socket times out. Is this not what you wanted?

Comment: Sadly not, I only want to be notified once if the socket times out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want code that sends an email whenever the socket which is trying to connect to a port is timing out. This can be achieved by doing this with your code:

```
import socket
import sys
import time
import datetime
import os
import logging

logging.basicConfig(filename='/var/log/syslog', level=logging.DEBUG,
                    format='%(asctime)s %(message)s',
                    datefmt='%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p')

log = logging.getLogger(__name__)

escalated = False
while True:
    time.sleep(1)
    for remote_port in [514]:
        sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        sock.settimeout(60)
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        now_text = now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")


        try:
            sock.connect((remote_host, remote_port))
            print((now_text, 'Port is Open on', remote_port))
            escalated = False


        except (socket.timeout, ConnectionRefusedError):
            if not escalated: 
                log.error('#### Syslog DR Invoked - Immediate action required ####')
                os.system("mail -s '# INVESTIGATE IMMEDIATELY - SYSLOG1 port 514 "
                      "unreachable #' alert@test.com < ./panic.txt")
                escalated = True
            print('Port is closed')

    sock.close()
```

Comment: This is great thanks, Ideally I want to keep the script running so I don't have to restart it once the server comes back online. For now, i'll increase the time out. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: I added a check to it - it now only notifies you if it previously worked - meaning you'll only receive one mail until the port is open again. If this solved your problem, consider marking the answer as accepted.

Comment: if you want to keep track of multiple ports, suggested by the `for` loop you're using, you'll have to track the `escalated` value in a `dict` instead of a simple bool. Otherwise it will not work properly.

Comment: For now, it's just the one port, though there could be a requirement in the future for more than one port. I have tested and it works well, I cannot thank you enough.